# Kendo UI - DataSource works when using fetch(), but not read()

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI DataSource that works when I use fetch(), but when I use the exact same configurtation with read() it fails. This is a problem as I need to retrieve data more than once and I can't do that with fetch().

Here is the DataSource code -

```
       var FieldsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport:  {
        read: {
            url: "../WebServiceAddress",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false
        },                  
        parameterMap: function() {
            return   "{some mapping that has been confirmed to work}";
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                if (data && data.d) {
                    //execution gets to here and stops
                    return data.d;          
                }
                else {
                    return [];
                }
            },
        }  

    });
```

Here is the code that calls the DataSource.read() function -

```
     function loadFields() {
        FieldsDataSource.read(function() {
            var data = this.data();
            if (data.length > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dataitem = data[i].Key;
                    $("#" + dataitem + "_field").prop("checked", data[i].Value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If I change `FieldsDataSource.read(function()`  to `FieldsDataSource.fetch(function()` everything works, but that doesn't make sense as I was under the improession that read and fetch do the same thing the difference being fetch only gets data once.

What I do know is that the data is being returned from the server, I can see it in fiddler - but the execution stops in the schema section where I flagged it in my code sample.

Apologies if I am asking a really obvious question, but I'm very new to Kendo.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the kendo demo site, this post explains how to read [remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/datasource/remote-data.html) quite nicely. I beleive the [schema.data](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) requires only string value. Configure your [model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.model) and [parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) and then just call read(), your datasource.data collection will get populated and then you can play with it.

Also note that datasource.read() is async, thefore you populatefields method should be called from complete event of the datasource, not other way around. eg you might have no data in when populating.

```
transport:  {
        read: {
            url: "../WebServiceAddress",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            complete : function () {    }
        },
```